# node_load get blank

Tags: 7, nodes

My `page.tpl.php` structure is:

```
<ul>
    <li id="creative-events">
    <div class="info animate-in">
    <?php node_load($nid = 10); ?>
    </div>
    <img class="sky animate-in" src="themes/bc/imagesx/bc_1.png" alt="Blue Sky" />
    <img class="balloon animate-in" src="themes/bc/imagesx/balloon.png" alt="Balloon" />
</li>
```

But not found my node. It's like this on Firebug:

```
<div class="info animate-in" style="">
                                            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used this codes and working!

```
$view_mode = 'teaser'; // Or 'full' for example

$node = node_load(1473);

$view = node_view($node, $view_mode);

print render($view);
```

But still want to know where I went wrong.

Comment: `node_load` just loads the node. No `print` or `render`