# node_load is not working

Tags: nodes, 6

I am creating a import script, which is importing node into Drupal website from external database.

Node is inserting properly. I have added condition that node exist into Drupal website or not and I am getting the correct nid with  this condition.

When I am using `node_load` to load the existing node, its showing empty result.

I also checked [node_load get blank](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52387/node-load-get-blank), but did not get any satisfied answer.

Please forgive me if this question is duplicate.

Code Snippets:

```
$pricelist_query = db_query("select * from abshop_import.abshop_import_price where (result != 'I' and  result != 'O' and result != 'D') or result is NUll limit 0, 50");

$message = '';

while ($pricelist_object = db_fetch_object($pricelist_query)) {

    $product = db_fetch_object(db_query("select * from abshop_import.abshop_import_antibodies where (result != 'I' or result is NUll) and sku_model='%s'", $pricelist_object -> sku_model));

    if (!empty($product)) {

    $product_object = db_fetch_object(db_query("select nid from {content_field_pr_man_prd_numb} where field_pr_man_prd_numb_value='" . $product -> field_pr_man_prd_numb_value . "'"));

        //If product is primary antibodies
        if ($product -> primary_or_secondary == 'P' || $product -> primary_or_secondary == 'p') {

        //If there is no existing product
            if (empty($product_object)) {

                $node = new STDCLASS;
                $node -> type = 'primary_antibodies';

                //setting language of the node
                $node -> language = 'en';

                //setting the author of the node
                $node -> uid = $product -> uid;

            } else {

                $nid = $product_object -> nid;

                $node = node_load($nid, NULL, TRUE);

                print $product_object -> nid . "===>";

                print_r($node);

            }

            $node -> shippable = 1;

            $node -> model = $product -> sku_model;

            //Setting title of the product
            $node -> title = $product -> title;
            //Setting body of the product
            $node -> body = $product -> body_teaser;
            //Setting teaser of the product
            $node -> teaser = $product -> body_teaser;

            $node -> weight = $product -> uc_products_weight;
            $node -> weight_units = $product -> uc_products_weight_units;

        }

        //If product is primary antibodies
        elseif ($product -> primary_or_secondary == 'S' || $product -> primary_or_secondary == 's') {

            //If there is no existing product
            if (empty($product_object)) {

                $node = new STDCLASS;

                $node -> type = 'secondary_antibodies';
                //setting language of the node
                $node -> language = 'en';

                //setting the author of the node
                $node -> uid = $product -> uid;

            } else {

                $nid = $product_object -> nid;

                $node = node_load(array('nid' => $nid), NULL, TRUE);

                print $product_object -> nid . "===>";

                $n = node_load(array('nid' => $nid), NULL, TRUE);
                print_r($n);

            }

            $node -> model = $product -> sku_model;

            $node -> shippable = 1;

            //Setting title of the product
            $node -> title = $product -> title;
            //Setting body of the product
            $node -> body = $product -> body_teaser;
            //Setting teaser of the product
            $node -> teaser = $product -> body_teaser;


            $node -> weight = $product -> uc_products_weight;
            $node -> weight_units = $product -> uc_products_weight_units;

        }

        if ($node = node_submit($node)) {

            print_r($node);
            die ;

            node_save($node);
        }

        node_load(FALSE, NULL, TRUE);

}
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are several possibilities but chances are you are not correctly creating all the data for your node. One example would be if the node type value you insert isn't defined as a content type. So I would suggest you compare the table rows created by your import process with ones created if you create nodes manually.

Comment: some code would definitely help :)

Comment: @Jimajamma, I have updated my question.

Comment: thanks.  when you do your debug printing, does `$nid` show a value that does in fact correspond to a valid node because your `node_load()`s appear correct.

Comment: @Jimajamma, yes nid showing the correct value, but `node_load` is not working. I have found another issue that url `node/148272/edit` is also not working. So, no idea what is happening here.

Comment: does `node/148272` display the node correctly?

Comment: @Jimajamma, no its showing `page not found` error, but when I am checking `{node}` table in database, `148272` is exist in database.

Comment: Does the node also have a uid that matches a user in the system and is there an entry in the node_revisions table for the node?

Comment: @Jimajamma, thanks for your support. I just noticed that there is no matching uid of node with system. I was updating my comment but before that I received your comment.

Comment: @Jimajamma, I have another question that we are sharing the `{users}` table with other drupal website, should `uid` exist in `{users}` table of the current website or it will use the main database table.

Comment: @rooby, Thanks for your support. When you post your comments, I was posting my comment at same time, so did not notice you. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After perform R&D, I found that `uid` of the node was not matching with `uid` in `{users}` table, which mean there is no existing user which is author of the node.

As I am importing the node from external database and it was importing properly previously, so I did not noticed the same.

Now, when I changed the `uid` of the node, everything starts working properly.